# Can't retrieve link from webpage

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using bs4 to run through a bunch of websites and grab a specific link off each page but I am having an issue grabbing that link.

I have tried getting all the links using.

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,"lxml")
 print(soup.find_all('a'))
```

I have tried many other ways including telling it the exact address of one site.

but every time seems to return everything but the link I want.

For context my code goes to pages of this site
https://ce.naco.org/?find=true

These are two of many pages that I am searching for the link in
https://ce.naco.org/?county_info=06019
https://ce.naco.org/?county_info=08045

Under "COUNTY CONTACT" there is a link in most of these pages and that is the link I want to grab but I just can't find a way to make it return only that link it just seems to be invisible to bs4.

I think it has something to do with how the page loads data based on what the user clicks and since bs4 isn't interacting with the site it doesn't load the data??? but this is just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of scraping the page, just use this endpoint to grab the data:

`https://ce.naco.org/get/county?fips=06019`

Here's how:

```py
import requests

data = requests.get("https://ce.naco.org/get/county?fips=06019").json()
print(f'{data["county"]["Full_Address"]}\n{data["county"]["County_Website"]}')
```

Output:

```
2281 Tulare St<br>Hall Of Records<br>Fresno, CA 93721-2105
http://www.co.fresno.ca.us
```

This works for both `county codes`:

```py
import requests

county_codes = ["06019", "08045"]

with requests.Session() as s:
    for county_code in county_codes:
        data = requests.get(f"https://ce.naco.org/get/county?fips={county_code}").json()
        print(f'{data["county"]["Full_Address"]}\n{data["county"]["County_Website"]}')
```

Output:

```
2281 Tulare St<br>Hall Of Records<br>Fresno, CA 93721-2105
http://www.co.fresno.ca.us
108 8Th St<br>Glenwood Springs, CO 81601-3355
http://www.garfield-county.com/
```

Comment: thanks this is very helpful. Few questions: How did you find the link (https://ce.naco.org/get/county?fips=06019)? Is this some form of site map? Are there similar pages on other websites JUST contain data like this one? How can I accesses pages like this on other sites? Knowing this would solve a lot of the problems I have had recently.

Comment: I'll tell you if you accept the answer. ;)

Comment: It's not a sitemap. A `sitemap` looks like [this](https://www.google.com/sitemap.xml). What you have is an API endpoint. All sites fetch data from somewhere. Some have it all in the source HTML, others get some or even all data from API's. You can see what happens behind the scenes using Developer's Tool. It's in any browser. Google this up. Then go to Network Tab and then XHR tab. Refresh the page, for example, one of the links with the code from your question. You'll see the link I used.